# How to convert string (Jul 21 2013 12:00:00:000AM) To Date

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I have a String which i want to convert it in date my string is:

```
NSString * DOBStr = @"Jul 21 2013 12:00:00:000AM";
```

I have tried this code but no luck getting string value null

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:sssa"];
    //also Tried
    //[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"LLL dd yyyy HH:mm:sssa"];
    //[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"LLL dd yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];
    //[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];
    NSDate *tmpDOBDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:DOBStr];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YYYY"];
    NSString *tmpDOBStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:tmpDOBDate];
    NSLog(@"tmpDOBStr : %@",tmpDOBStr);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSSa` for your format.